# Error evaluation of consecutive terms at fixed point iteration methods.

Tags: numerical-methods

**Q:** Give an evaluation of error between two consecutive terms for methods of type $p_{n+1}=g(p_{n})$.

I tried solving it, but I think that my solution is correct only when the method converges to a fixed point, or when the function that we consider fulfills the fixed point theorem, which gives the necessary conditions for existence and uniqueness of a fixed point. Let me give you an idea about what theorem states:

**Theorem.**
If $g \in C[a,b]$ and $g(x) \in [a,b]$ for all $x \in [a,b]$,  then $g$ has at least one fixed point in $[a,b]$.
If, in addition, $g'(x)$ exists on $(a,b)$ and a positive constant $k<1$ exists with $|g'(x)| \leq k$, for all $x \in (a,b)$ then there is exactly one fixed point in $[a,b]$.

First I tried something like this, considering that the questions states that the fixed point theorem stands, and using the Mean Value Theorem:

$|p_{n+1}-p_{n}|=|g(p_{n})-g(p_{n-1})|=|g'(\epsilon)||p_{n}-p_{n-1}| \leq k|p_{n}-p_{n-1}| \leq ... \leq k^n|p_1-p_0|.$

But then, what if we don't know that every derivative of our function at points between $(p_i,p_{i-1})$ for $i \in {1,2,...,n}$ is bounded by $k$? So my dilemma is here, does the question imply that the fixed point theorem stands, and if not necessary, can we consider that the solution is a two-part solution, and the first part is the one that I stated, and the second part is this one?(or is only this one, because the scope of this solution goes beyond the first part, or what I'm doing is totally wrong):

If we take $M_1, M_2, ... , M_n$ as the bounds of our derivative functions at $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2, ..., \epsilon_n$, $\epsilon_i \in (p_i,p_{i-1}), i \in {1,2,...,n}$ i.e $|g'(\epsilon_1)| \leq M_1,|g'(\epsilon_2)| \leq M_2,...,|g'(\epsilon_n)| \leq M_n$ where $M_i \in \mathbb{R}, i\in{1,2,3,...,n}$ and $M= M_1\cdot M_2 \cdot ... \cdot M_n$.

$|p_{n+1}-p_{n}|=|g(p_{n})-g(p_{n-1})|=|g'(\epsilon_1)||p_{n}-p_{n-1}| \leq M_1|p_{n}-p_{n-1}| = M_1|g(p_{n-1})-g(p_{n-2})|=M_1|g'(\epsilon_2)||p_{n-1}-p_{n-2}|\leq M_1M_2|p_{n-1}-p_{n-2}|\leq ... \leq M_1M_2\cdot...\cdot M_n|p_1-p_0|=M|p_1-p_0|.$

What if our function does not converge? Can we give an evaluation(approximation)?
If my tries are not correct, please give me an idea how to answer that question.
Thank you!

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. I'd suggest that you state in your solution that you assume $k := \sup_{\xi \in [a, b]} |g'(\xi)|$ to be finite. You could assume less, namely that $g$ is Lipschitz continuous.